# Javascript loop json for value and apply if condition met

Tags: javascript, json

If I had the following JSON,

```
[{},{"param":"#content","value":"K2-12M","quantity":1,"q_id":3,"clear":1}
{"param":"#content","value":"K2-12F","quantity":2,"q_id":3,"clear":0}]
```

In js/jquery, how would I loop through, and if any of the items have `"clear":0`, then set ALL items to `"clear":0` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var clear;
for( var i=0, l=json.length; i<l; i++ ){
    if( 0 === json[i].clear ){
        clear = true;
        break;
    }
}

if( clear ){
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
        json[i].clear = 0;
    }
}
```

---

or using jQuery (this is less efficient):

```
$( json ).filter(
    function( ix, obj ){
        return 0 === obj.clear;
    }
).length
    && $( json ).each(
        function( ix, obj ){
            obj.clear = 0;
        }
    );
```

Comment: I think he wants to catch conditions where `clear=0`, and then set clear to 0... So wouldn't you have to change `if(json[i].clear)` to `if(json[i].clear == 0)` , and then later set `json[i].clear = 0;`?

Comment: @Chazbot is correct, except all that needed changing was the if condition.

Answer (score 2):

Nested for-loop:

```
for(var i = 0, l = json.length; i < l; i++ ){
    if(json[i].clear == 0){
        for(var x = 0; x < l; x++) {
            json[x].clear = 0;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dS7XR/2) for your fiddling pleasure.